# Знак препинания после слов автора перед диалогом

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь, диалог, двоеточие

*Я часто наблюдаю, что люди общаются примерно так(. / :)*

*— Я на работе занимаюсь...*

*— Круто! А я делаю проекты по...*

*— Это очень интересно! А меня обещают скоро повысить, и тогда я...*

*В общем, каждый говорит только о себе и из вежливости выслушивает другого.*

---

Подскажите, какой знак ставится после слов автора при вводе диалога, с ссылкой на правило. Что-то не могу у Розенталя и Лопатина такое найти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы поставил двоеточие (чисто интуитивно). Мне кажется, для предложения, вводящего диалог, это допустимо (по аналогии со словами автора, вводящими первую реплику). Вот похожие примеры из Нацкорпуса:

> Затем состоялся примерно такой **диалог:** ― Хэлло! Я Энн Фридмен. ― Очень приятно. [Сергей Довлатов. Переводные картинки // «Иностранная литература», 1990]
>
> Взрослый автор в силу сатирического, если не сказать цинично-саркастического, тридцатидевятилетнего опыта наблюдения за человеческой природой уже слышит этот вполне возможный **диалог:** ― Значит, вы утверждаете, что когда вам было пять лет, вы страстно хотели потрогать мёртвую собаку? ― Да. ― Как вы себе представляли эту собаку? [Татьяна Соломатина. Большая собака, или «Эклектичная живописная вавилонская повесть о зарытом» (2009)]

Answer (score 2):

Я часто наблюдаю, что люди общаются примерно так (следующим образом). **Ставим точку, так как дальше идет развернутое раскрытие темы.**

**Вопрос № 290182**
Добрый день, подскажите,  в каких случаях мы используем точку после слова "следующее", в каких двоеточие? Заранее благодарю.

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
Действует следующее правило. Точка ставится в конце предложения, вводящего в **дальнейшее развернутое изложение:** Вот этот рассказ. (Пауст.) [дальше следует рассказ]; Представьте себе следующее. [дальше — подробное повествование]; Новый станок имеет такое устройство. [дальше — пространное описание].

После слова следующее будет уместно поставить двоеточие, если дальнейшее изложение не очень велико.